# Angular - Showing Hiding Spinner when RxJs Subscription is active

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I want to implement a directive to show a spinner on top of a container element.
e.g. consider the following scenario

```
<component [spinner]="{subs: [usersSub, accountsSub], latency: 500}"></component>
```

Here `[spinner]` is the directive that receives object as param which contains:

1. **subs**: array of *RxJS Subscriptions* to show spinner whenever any of these subscriptions are loading.
2. **latency**: time in ms to show spinner if request exceeds this time.

I know how to show a spinner's dom on top of components dom. I need help in monitoring subscriptions.

Comment: what have you tried so far in the spinner directive? and by subscriptions do you actually mean the return value of `Observable.whatever(..).subscriber(..)` right?

Comment: Yes, I meant Observable.subscribe.
Or if it's easier to use subscribed observable itself,  not sure.

Comment: I don't think you can really do that much with the subscriptions themselves, I'd rather pass the Observables as input and inside the directive class merge all of them and start building from there.

Comment: See [angular2-busy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-busy). It takes array of subscriptions.
The idea is to show spinner on concerning subscriber i.e. we might want to show spinner only on a specific subscription to an observable that has more than one subscriptions.

Comment: I looked at it and you can check the status of the subscription via the `closed` property. I think you could create an Observable from the input value so every time the input changes you emit a new value with the status of the subscription.

Comment: In docs it sayas `closed: boolean. A flag to indicate whether this Subscription has already been unsubscribed.` We are not unsubscribing here.

Comment: Yes, but after a stream is terminated (wether `complete` or `error` are called), the subscriber unsubscribes automatically. However, this will not work for `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject`, since those never complete. Now, please provide some code implementation or I will not be able to help you anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158861/discussion-between-abdul-wahab-and-osman-cea).

Answer (score 0):

**How to monitor subscriptions**

The library you referenced in comments, ***angular-2-busy***, monitors subscriptions by adding them to an array and also using the subscription's `add()` method to add a teardown method which is called when the subscription unsubscribes.

See this from RxJs 5.5.2 source, Subscription.ts

```js
add(teardown: TeardownLogic): Subscription {
  ...
```

The teardown function removes the subscription from the monitor array, so when this array is empty the spinner stops.

I am wondering what it is about ***angular-2-busy*** that you don't like or will improve upon in your own directive?

**When does a subscription unsubscribe**

On this question, the source for Subscriber has these internal functions so the subscription unsubscribes on either complete or error events (and of course when unsubscribe is called explicitly).

```js
Subscriber.prototype._complete = function () {
    this.destination.complete();
    this.unsubscribe();
};

Subscriber.prototype._error = function (err) {
    this.destination.error(err);
    this.unsubscribe();
};
```

Subscriptions that don't complete or error will keep the spinner spinning.

Comment: I don't want to use **angular2-buys**'s template, I am impressed by it's use of subscriptions, min and max approach,  though.

Comment: Yes, I probably wouldn't use angular2-busy either, but I like the concept you raise of monitoring subscriptions to control a spinner. Am currently doing it via middleware in a Redux store.

Comment: Subscriber is new to me. If I have an Observable or Subscription, how I'll get a subscriber?

Comment: Well, if you assign a subscription to a variable e.g `const sub = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).subscribe()` and console.log it, it shows up as a Subscriber. And the `subscribe()` method of Observable returns a 'sink' that is created from a toSubscriber method. That said, there is another class called Subscrption! Someone should draw a diagram.